# Eigen::Matrix contained inside a struct is marked as non-writeable by pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm using `pybind11` to create a Python binding for my C++ library that uses Eigen types. However, when I try to bind a struct that contains an `Eigen::Matrix`, the corresponding generated Python class has all the `ndarray` (the Python destination class for `Eigen::Matrix` members) elements with the Writeable flag set to false, which are therefore non-modifiable. I've managed to reduce my problem to the following MWE:

```
// binding.cpp
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/eigen.h"

struct Example {
   Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> m;
};

namespace py = pybind11;
PYBIND11_MODULE(MyBinding, m)
{
   py::class_<Example>(m, "Example")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def_readwrite("m", &Example::m);
}
```

```
# script.py
import MyBinding
ex = MyBinding.Example()
# ex.m has Writeable flag equal to false!
```

On the contrary, when binding the following code, everything works as expected, i.e. the value returned by `f`, when called in Python, is modifiable (has the Writeable flag set to true):

```
Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1> f() {
   return {};
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(MyBinding, m)
{
   m.def("f", &f);
}
```

What am I missing here? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def_readwrite(⋯)` is a shortcut for `def_property(⋯)` [(source link)](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/f6c4c1047a293ea77223c21f84f888e062212d78/include/pybind11/pybind11.h#L1185-L1192) where the getter takes the class instance by `const`-reference.  Therefore the resulting numpy array is not modifiable.

All you need to do is to write custom getter and setter functions:

```cpp
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE( MyBinding, m )
{
    py::class_<Example>( m, "Example" )
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def_property( "m",
            // Getter
            []( Example const& self )
            {
                return self.m;
            },
            // Setter
            []( Example& self, Eigen::Matrix<double,3,1> const& val )
            {
                self.m = val;
            }
        )
    ;
}
```

**Caution:** untested code, you may need to pass an extra return-value policy argument